# Android - ListView not being updated after adding to SQLite database unless app is restarted

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am currently trying to populate a ListView by querying a SQLite database which feeds the adapter, which I can update by adding an entry.  However, the ListView doesn't get updated unless I restart the app.

Here is my data source code:

```
public class DataSource {

    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private SQLHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns = null;

    public DataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new SQLHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public Person addPerson(String firstname, String lastname) {    
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SQLHelper.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
        values.put(SQLHelper.COLUMN_LASTNAME, lastname);

        long insertId = database.insert(SQLHelper.TABLE_PEOPLE, null, values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLHelper.TABLE_PEOPLE, allColumns, SQLHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Person newPerson = cursorToPerson(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newPerson;
    }

    public List<Person> getAllPeople() {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLHelper.TABLE_PEOPLE, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Person person = cursorToPerson(cursor);
            people.add(person);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return people;
    }

    private Person cursorToPerson(Cursor cursor) {
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            person.setFirstname(cursor.getString(1));
            person.setLastname(cursor.getString(1));
            return person;
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

And here is SQLHelper:

```
public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "people.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Table
    public static final String TABLE_PEOPLE = "people";

    // Columns
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "first_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_LASTNAME = "last_name";

    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_PEOPLE + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " text not null, " + COLUMN_LASTNAME + " text not null);";

    public SQLHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(SQLHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data"); 
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PEOPLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

To populate my ListView adapter, I call the `getAllPeople()` method.  To add to my database, I call the `addPerson()` method.  The ListView is inside a dialog.

Is there any particular reason why I must restart my app for the ListView to be updated with the new person?

Comment: read google's "android notepad tutorial" and you will see how easily it can be done using `[Simple]CursorAdapter` and custom `ContentProvider`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must notify your adapter about data changed. Depending on type of adapter you need to either call `swapCursor()` or `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

Did you call notifyDataSetChanged everytime you add a Person?